# ¿Como obtener un valor de un arrayList en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist

Tengo el siguiente ArrayList el cual lleno con información de una base de datos

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> employeeList;
employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
public static final String TAG_DESIGNATION = "designation";

Log.d("INICIA ","employeeList= "+employeeList);
```

En el Logcat me da lo siguiente:

```
D/INICIA: employeeList= [{designation=manager, name=rick}]
```

Todo funciona bien pero tengo una duda como podria acceder al valor `manager` que se encuentra en el arrayList para poder utilizarlo en una condición

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A. Si hay un sólo par de valores**

Basta con obtener dicho valor por el nombre de su clave en el HashMap que has creado. El get(0) busca el primer (y en este caso único valor) dentro del mapa:

```
String sDesignation= employeeList.get(0).get("designation");
```

La variable **`sDesignation`** tendrá el valor `manager`en este caso.

**B. Si hay varios pares de valores en el mapa**

Si hay varios pares de valores en el array la lectura se suele hacer dentro de un bucle (for, while...).

**Ejemplo con Iterator y While**:

```
/*
 *Este ejemplo obtiene, en el caso de que haya varios valores, 
 *en la variable `key` la llave (designation, name...) 
 *y en la variable `value` los valores de cada llave (manager, rick...)
 */

Iterator myIterator = employeeList.keySet().iterator();
while(myIterator.hasNext()) {
    String key=(String)myIterator.next();
    String value=(String)employeeList.get(key);
}
```

**Ejemplo con bucle for**

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : employeeList)
     for (Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet())
        {
        String key = mapEntry.getKey();
        String value = mapEntry.getValue();
        }
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono perfecto

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a tu ArrayList, contiene un HashMap con keys `designation` y `name` :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> employeeList;
```

Puedes obtener los valores mediante el indice

```
for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i ++) {
   Log.d("INICIA ","designation= "+employeeList.get(i).get("designation"));  
   Log.d("INICIA ","name= "+employeeList.get(i).get("name"));          
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, justo acababa de marcar como valida la otra respuesta :(